# Is there a difference in how bitfields behave depending on the underlying type width?

Tags: c, embedded, bit-fields, texas-instruments, peripherals

I am defining some registers (they're all 32-bits wide) to interface with a hardware peripheral using bitfields. At first I defined everything by mixing `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, and `uint32_t` types. For example:

```
... 
// More definitions above
union  {
    volatile uint32_t I2C_REVNB_HI;

    volatile struct {
        uint16_t FUNC   : 12;
        uint8_t RSVD0   : 2;
        uint8_t SCHEME  : 2;
        uint16_t RSVD1  : 16;
    } I2C_REVNB_HI_bits;
}; // 0x04 - 0x08
...
// More definitions below
```

When a bitfield is  `bits <= 8` I assign it to a `uint8_t`, and similarly when `8 < bits <= 16` I assigned it to a `uint16_t` and `16 < bits <= 32` to a `uint32_t` . This looked a bit messy to me however and I refactored everything to be `uint32_t` regardless of the bit width since I assumed it would not matter:

```
... 
// More definitions above
union  {
    volatile uint32_t I2C_REVNB_HI;

    volatile struct {
        uint32_t FUNC    : 12;
        uint32_t RSVD0   : 2;
        uint32_t SCHEME  : 2;
        uint32_t RSVD1   : 16;
    } I2C_REVNB_HI_bits;
}; // 0x04 - 0x08
...
// More definitions below
```

I tried running my code with both implementations of the register definitions, but the one where everything is `uint32_t` seems to not work; the peripheral is not behaving as expected. So my question is, does anything happen under the hood that is different between the two implementations? I assumed there would be no difference since all bit fields are the same length as before. I could not really find anything online about this.

PS. The code I am writing is to run on one of the Programmable Real-time Units of the [AM335X processor](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruh73q/spruh73q.pdf), to interface with the I2C peripheral and is compiled using the [clpru compiler](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruhv7c/spruhv7c.pdf?ts=1707335511790).

Some notes from the clpru compiler document on bit-fields (p108) that may or may not be useful:

- "Bit fields are handled using the declared type"
- "Bit fields declared volatile are accessed according to the bit field's declared type. A volatile bit field
  reference generates exactly one reference to its storage; multiple volatile bit field accesses are not
  merged"
- "The size of a struct containing the bit field depends on the declared type of the bit field. For example,
  both of these structs have a size of 4 bytes:"

```
    struct st {int a:4};
    struct st {char a:4; int :22;};
```

And on (p69) of the compiler manual:

"In addition to _Bool, signed int, and unsigned int, the compiler allows char, signed char, unsigned char,
signed short, unsigned shot, signed long, unsigned long, signed long long, unsigned long long, and
enum types as bit-field types."

**Update 1**

I tried to check if there was any difference assigning to the fields as suggested by @IanAbbot:

```
i2c_refactored.I2C_REVNB_HI = 0;
i2c_refactored.I2C_REVNB_HI_bits.SCHEME = ~0;
i2c_refactored.I2C_REVNB_HI_bits.FUNC   = ~0;
DEBUG_MEMORY_0.status = i2c_refactored.I2C_REVNB_HI;

i2c_original.I2C_REVNB_HI = 0;
i2c_original.I2C_REVNB_HI_bits.SCHEME = ~0;
i2c_original.I2C_REVNB_HI_bits.FUNC   = ~0;
DEBUG_MEMORY_1.status = i2c_original.I2C_REVNB;
```

But the outputs are the same: `0x0000CFFF` (or `0b00000000000000001100111111111111`)

**Update 2**

After trying to set all fields to `unsigned int` instead of `uint32_t`, the faulty behaviour still occurs

**Update 3**

I made the following simple testcase:

```
int main(void){

    volatile pru_I2C_tmp i2c_refactored = {0};
    volatile pru_I2C i2c_working = {0};

    i2c_refactored.I2C_REVNB_HI = 0;
    i2c_refactored.I2C_REVNB_HI_bits.SCHEME = ~0;
    i2c_refactored.I2C_REVNB_HI_bits.FUNC   = ~0;
    DEBUG_MEM0.status = i2c_refactored.I2C_REVNB_HI;

    i2c_working.I2C_REVNB_HI = 0;
    i2c_working.I2C_REVNB_HI_bits.SCHEME = ~0;
    i2c_working.I2C_REVNB_HI_bits.FUNC   = ~0;
    DEBUG_MEM1.status = i2c_working.I2C_REVNB_HI;

    __halt();
    return 0;
}
```

With the corresponding ASM ([manual link](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruij2/spruij2.pdf?ts=1701517453138&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)):

```
[0x0000] 0x240000c0    LDI R0.w2, 0x0000
[0x0001] 0x24080080    LDI R0.w0, 0x0800
[0x0002] 0x0504e0e2    SUB R2, R0, 0x04
[0x0003] 0x2eff818e    UNKNOWN-F2
[0x0004] 0x230007c3    JAL R3.w2, 0x0007
[0x0005] 0x240001ee    LDI R14, 0x0001
[0x0006] 0x230040c3    JAL R3.w2, 0x0040
[0x0007] 0x05ffe2e2    SUB R2, R2, 0xff
[0x0008] 0x240800ef    LDI R15, 0x0800
[0x0009] 0x2400d8f0    LDI R16, 0x00d8
[0x000a] 0xe1fd02c3    SBBO R3.b2, R2, 253, 2
[0x000b] 0x05b3e2e2    SUB R2, R2, 0xb3
[0x000c] 0x0100e2ee    ADD R14, R2, 0x00
[0x000d] 0x230033c3    JAL R3.w2, 0x0033
[0x000e] 0x2408d8ef    LDI R15, 0x08d8
[0x000f] 0x2400d8f0    LDI R16, 0x00d8
[0x0010] 0x01d8e2ee    ADD R14, R2, 0xd8
[0x0011] 0x230033c3    JAL R3.w2, 0x0033
[0x0012] 0x240000e0    LDI R0, 0x0000
[0x0013] 0x24c000e1    LDI R1, 0xc000
[0x0014] 0xe1042280    SBBO R0, R2, 4, 4
[0x0015] 0x0104e2e0    ADD R0, R2, 0x04
[0x0016] 0xf100208e    LBBO R14, R0, 0, 4
[0x0017] 0x12e1eee1    OR R1, R14, R1
[0x0018] 0xe1002081    SBBO R1, R0, 0, 4
[0x0019] 0x240fffe1    LDI R1, 0x0fff
[0x001a] 0xf100208e    LBBO R14, R0, 0, 4
[0x001b] 0x12e1eee1    OR R1, R14, R1
[0x001c] 0x2eff818e    UNKNOWN-F2
[0x001d] 0xe1002081    SBBO R1, R0, 0, 4
[0x001e] 0x240001c1    LDI R1.w2, 0x0001
[0x001f] 0x24000081    LDI R1.w0, 0x0000
[0x0020] 0xf1042280    LBBO R0, R2, 4, 4
[0x0021] 0xe1002180    SBBO R0, R1, 0, 4
[0x0022] 0x240001c1    LDI R1.w2, 0x0001
[0x0023] 0x24024881    LDI R1.w0, 0x0248
[0x0024] 0xe1dc228e    SBBO R14, R2, 220, 4
[0x0025] 0xf1dd0200    LBBO R0, R2, 221, 1
[0x0026] 0x13c00000    OR R0.b0, R0.b0, 0xc0
[0x0027] 0xe1dd0200    SBBO R0, R2, 221, 1
[0x0028] 0x240fff80    LDI R0.w0, 0x0fff
[0x0029] 0xf1dc02c0    LBBO R0.b2, R2, 220, 2
[0x002a] 0x1280c080    OR R0.w0, R0.w2, R0.w0
[0x002b] 0xe1dc0280    SBBO R0, R2, 220, 2
[0x002c] 0xf1dc2280    LBBO R0, R2, 220, 4
[0x002d] 0xe1002180    SBBO R0, R1, 0, 4
[0x002e] 0x2a000000 >> HALT 
[0x002f] 0x01b3e2e2    ADD R2, R2, 0xb3
[0x0030] 0xf1fd02c3    LBBO R3.b2, R2, 253, 2
[0x0031] 0x01ffe2e2    ADD R2, R2, 0xff
[0x0032] 0x20c30000    JMP R3.w2
[0x0033] 0x5100f00c    QBEQ 12, R16, 0
[0x0034] 0x10eeeef1    AND R17, R14, R14
[0x0035] 0x24003000    LDI R0.b0, 0x0030
[0x0036] 0x70f00002    QBGE 2, R0.b0, R16
[0x0037] 0x10f0f000    AND R0.b0, R16, R16
[0x0038] 0x0400f0f0    SUB R16, R16, R0.b0
[0x0039] 0xff00cf12    LBBO R18, R15, 0, b0
[0x003a] 0xef00d112    SBBO R18, R17, 0, b0
[0x003b] 0x5100f004    QBEQ 4, R16, 0
[0x003c] 0x0000efef    ADD R15, R15, R0.b0
[0x003d] 0x0000f1f1    ADD R17, R17, R0.b0
[0x003e] 0x21003500    JMP 0x0035
[0x003f] 0x20c30000    JMP R3.w2
[0x0040] 0x230042c3    JAL R3.w2, 0x0042
[0x0041] 0x21004100    JMP 0x0041
[0x0042] 0x10000000    AND R0.b0, R0.b0, R0.b0
[0x0043] 0x20c30000    JMP R3.w2
```

`DEBUG_MEM0` is at address 0x10000 and `DEBUG_MEM1` at address 0x10248. The statements seem logical, albeit that there are some statements I don't fully understand. (`R2` is the stack pointer and `R14` the return register). Does anyone see anything that could hint to why it is not functioning?

Comment: Bitfields in C are a mess, where nothing about layout is certain. As a result, bitfields are always compiler and target platform specific. Read your compiler manual to see how bitfields are implemented. Or simply don't use them.

Comment: To begin with, the C standard only defines bit-fields of type `bool`, `int` and `unsigned int`. Your code is not standard C, so there is no portable or deterministic behavior to be found here.

Comment: @Lundin I just edited the question adding a statement from the compiler manual saying bit-fields support many types

Comment: If you want to see what is really happening I recommend you compile simple test with both versions, and then look into generated assembly to see how register locations are accessed.

Comment: @user694733 I was hoping to avoid doing this but if there is no standard explanation for this behaviour I suppose I will have to dig into the disassembly

Comment: You could check the layout of a bitfield by zeroing out `foo.I2C_REVNB_HI_bits`, setting one of the members of `foo.I2C_REVNB_HI_bits` to `~0`, and then printing the value of `foo.I2C_REVNB_HI`.

Comment: If you want the bit-fields to be in one storage unit, use the same type for all of them.  Don’t switch between `uint16_t` and `uint8_t`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that is exactly what I did though, and that seems to be the version that works. Assigning everything to uint32_t is what broke the code

Comment: @IanAbbott I tried this but sadly I discovered nothing strange (see update)

Comment: Isn't the first struct be 5 bytes in size?

Comment: @ikegami the bits add up to 32

Comment: Yeah, tested. That first struct is BADLY written, then, cause that looks like a 16 bit field, a 8 bit field and a 16 bit field! (40 bits)

Comment: @ikegami that's why I wanted to refactor, but refactoring everything to be the same type causes wrong behaviour

Comment: Yes, cause you shouldn't be using bit fields if you want a specific order/placement.

Comment: In your **Update** 3 code, the bit-field members are only accessed to modify local variables, and it is the unioned 32-bit values that are written elsewhere. Is that also the case in the real code, or are the bit-field members accessed to modify the hardware registers directly?

Comment: @IanAbbott I create a pointer to the memory region where the peripheral registers are located and thus a change in the bit fields should reflect a change in the peripheral. And this is the case for the original register description I made as it functions as expected.

Comment: What is `sizeof i2c_refactored` compared to `sizeof i2c_working`?

Comment: @dbush both 216 bytes (0xD8)

Comment: Do not edit posts to change the question asked. Stack Overflow is not a personal assistance or debugging service. You should not treat posts as interactive sessions to diagnose problems. New questions should be asked in new posts (or worked on on your own).

Comment: 216 bytes! This is the union presented in the question, right? The one containing only members `I2C_REVNB_HI` and `I2C_REVNB_HI_bits`?  Compilers do have the freedom to lay out that union with an arbitrary amount of trailing padding, but it seems implausible that a compiler would in fact add so much.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The structure in which a whole group of these unions resides is in total 216 bytes, every union is 4 bytes (32 bits). Every union has a different layout (which can be found page 4601 of the AM335X manual I linked in the post). I only put one of them here for simplicity.

Comment: About update 3: you have already checked in update 1 that the end result is identical for the two structures. Thus, the interesting part is the assignment to the bit fields. You may try to simplify the example by just assigning the FUNC bits of each structure (see the example in my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

The C standard does not specify how an implementation lays out bit-fields in storage units. C 2018 6.7.2.1 11 says (emphasis added):

> An implementation may allocate **any** addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field…

So a C compiler is free to allocate one, two, or more bytes for a 2-bit bit-field, it is free to allocate two or more bytes for a 12-bit bit-field (assuming eight-bit bytes), and so on. It may base its decision based on the nominal type of the bit-field.

About the only constraint the standard imposes on selecting storage units is, also in 6.7.2.1 11:

> … If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit…

Answer (score 1):

> does anything happen under the hood that is different between the two implementations?

Not withstanding OP's *select* compiler documentation: "In addition to _Bool, signed int, and unsigned int, the compiler allows `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `signed short`, ...", concerning bit fields, `uint16_t, uint8_t, char, uint32_t` and many others types are not always well defined per the C spec.

Portable code that does not rely on *implementation defined behavior* should only use `bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`.

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type. It is implementation-defined whether atomic types are permitted.  C11dr §6.7.2.1 5

> ... except that for bitfields, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier `int` designates the same type as `signed int` or the same type as `unsigned int`. C11dr § 6.7.2 5

---

[C2X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C23_(C_standard_revision)) may change things.

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified `bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, **a bit-precise integer type**, or other implementation-defined type. It is implementation-defined whether atomic types are permitted. C23_n3096 § 6.7.2.1 5

This does not certainly include `char`.

Comment: I have tried by changing all bit fields to be of type `unsigned int` but this did not alter the faulty behaviour

Comment: @lrdewaal "the peripheral is not behaving as expected." lacks detail.  What is the peripheral?, What was the expected behavior?  What was noticed?

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, the behavior of bit fields in this case is not fully defined by the standard.

Without more information, it is difficult to say anything for sure, but this is a guess:

According to the OP information, in both cases, the struct is 32 bits and the bit layout seems to be identical. Suppose that e.g. the FUNC bits are written:

```
   bits.FUNC = 0x5;
```

The compiler must then generate code which reads at least 12 bits at the memory location corresponding to `bits.FUNC`, modifies the 12 bits corresponding to FUNC, and writes the result back. It seems that if the `FUNC` field is declared as `uint16_t`, then the compiler will do this via a 16-bit read/write, i.e. write back not only the `FUNC`-bits, but also the `RSVD0` and `SCHEME` bits. If the field is declared `uint32_t`, then it will do it via a 32-bit read/write which will also cover the `RSVD1` bits.

See [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/roGcTr1W5) for ARM showing exactly the described behavior:

```
        movs    r2, #5
  // Assignment to FUNC when declared uint16_t:
        ldrh    r3, [sp]
        bfi     r3, r2, #0, #12
        strh    r3, [sp]        @ movhi
  // Assignment to FUNC when declared uint32_t:
        ldr     r3, [sp, #4]
        bfi     r3, r2, #0, #12
        str     r3, [sp, #4]
```

Depending on the peripheral properties, this implicit write of the `RSVD1` bits could cause the unexpected behavior.

Comment: But would this then not also cause issues if, say a field of 2 bits is assigned to a uint8_t? The extra 6 bits would also overlap with other fields

Comment: @lrdewaal Yes, but since the processor generally speaking accesses data in bytes, it is likely that the peripheral registers are laid out so that the functionality is robust to this.

Comment: @nielsen while one would expect it, I've worked with peripheral implementations that were not byte addressable, or any write to the register would assume all 32 bits on the data bus were valid, leading to "undefined behavior" when accessing non-DWORD accesses.  Then there's read side effects to deal with, then write side effects that trigger events (rather than just updating values).  Hardware engineers making peripherals don't always grok what the mcu or compiler is going to do or expect

Answer (score 0):

> I am defining some registers (they're all 32-bits wide) to interface with a hardware peripheral using bitfields.

This is arguably a mistake.  If you need to pack several fields into an integer then shifts and bitmasks are the portable way to do it.  That's likely to also be how your compiler does it under the hood when you use bitfields, but if you do it yourself then you can control the layout details directly.

> Is there a difference in how bitfields behave depending on the underlying type width?

The C language allows implementations considerable latitude in how bitfields are laid out within a struct, and that layout is exposed in your case via the other member of your union.  It is well within the spec for an implementation to take the declared type of bitfield members into account in laying the containing structure.

However, I do not see a plausible explanation for the observed difference that is consistent with the asserted facts:

- the union containing the integer and the bitfield structure is exactly the same size (32 bits) as its `uint32_t` member
- in aggregate, the bitfields require the full size of the union
- the specific widths of the first three structure members will require them to be stored in the same ASU (assuming a machine with 8-bit bytes) to comply with C's layout rules
- experiment shows these to be laid out in the space corresponding to the two least-significant bytes of the integer, in the same relative positions in both cases
- the compiler is the [PRU Optimizing C/C++ Compiler v2.3](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruhv7c/spruhv7c.pdf?ts=1707335511790)

... unless something else has changed, or some other code not presented in the question is involved. In particular, I don't see any way that the compiler specified, operating as documented and observed on the code presented, is mapping bits of the bitfields to bits of the integer differently in one case than in the other.

The most likely explanation, then, is that some other code consuming the affected objects is sensitive to the types of the bitfield members. For example, it may be relevant that with the original code, if bitfield `I2C_REVNB_HI_bits.SCHEME` is subjected to the standard integer promotions then the resulting value has type `int`, whereas with the revised code, such a promotion will leave the type unchanged (`uint32_t`, which is `unsigned int` for this compiler).

Comment: I agree with the recommendation not to use bitfields, but besides from that, remember that the OP is mapping peripheral registers. It is not uncommon that reading or writing such a register has a side effect. As shown in my answer, the compiler is likely to generate different code in the two cases which could explain the observed difference in behavior.

Comment: @nielsen, it's not clear to me that "I am defining some registers [...] to interface with a hardware peripheral" means that they are actually mapping the union in question onto a register.  To me, the fact that it is part of a much larger object suggests not.  Nevertheless, you do have a point that if they *are* so mapping it, then differences in the generated machine code could be relevant.  On the third hand, if we infer semantics from the OP's field names, then we might conclude that only the bottom 16 bits of this particular register are relevant anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Storage of bitfields is some field in which compiler writers are given full freedom of implementation (this happens since K&R specification) and is the less portable feature of the C language.  If you want to use bitfields and be portable, just use `int` or `unsigned` as the type in the field, to create unsidned or signed bitfields.  The compiler will arrange them in an optimum way, but you will have poor and nonportable way of knowing how they are internally implemented, but if you are tied already to a compiler, there are good news.  Almost every compiler documents how they do the packing of bitfields into the structure, so you can follow that and use it to develop.  Just remember, that will be non-portable. If you want a portable solution, dont use bitfields.

Answer (score -1):

Given the original `struct` within the `union`:

```
        uint16_t FUNC   : 12;
        uint8_t RSVD0   : 2;
        uint8_t SCHEME  : 2;
        uint16_t RSVD1  : 16;
```

I suspect the compiler is working along the lines of:

- The first 12 bits fit into a `uint16_t` — no problem.
- The next 2 bits are in a different data type; start a new storage unit (the same size as the new type — `uint8_t`).
- The next 2 bits are of the same type and fit into that storage unit.
- The last 16 bits are in a different type again (and wouldn't fit into a storage unit the size of a `uint8_t` anyway); start a new storage unit (the same size as the new type — `uint16_t`).  Further, because of the alignment requirement for `uint16_t`, add a padding byte after the prior storage unit.

If you use `uint16_t` for all the bit-fields, or if you use `uint32_t` for them all, you will probably get the result you want.

What I describe is, I believe, permitted by the standard. The standard barely mandates anything for bit-fields, though.  Basically, all uses of bit-fields are subject to the whims of the 'implementation' — meaning, subject to the whims of the compiler.  For details, see (C11) [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1), especially paragraphs 4, 5, 9-12.

One more issue to worry about is whether the first bit-field is in the most significant bits or the least significant bits.  Have you verified what is used on your platform?  Again, the standard does not specify how the bits are laid out, whether that's most to least significant or vice versa, nor where padding bits are placed.

Comment: I would have guessed the same thing that you have, but the OP says that the version where all the declared bitfield types are `uint32_t` is the one that doesn't work.